# Creating a loop to draw circles in python

Tags: python

stuck on a simple task any help would be much appreciated. It creates a graphic window, and depending on where the user clicks it will draw a different colour circle. Right hand = Yellow and the left hand will be red depending on where the user clicks. However i cant get my if statement to work, and all its returning is 10 yellow circles. Any help would be appreciated , thanks

```
def circles():
win = GraphWin ("circles", 400,100)
for i in range (10):
    point = win.getMouse()
    circleFill = Circle(point, 10)
    circleFill.draw(win)
    if str(point) >= str(200):
        circleFill = Circle (point, 10)
        circleFill.setFill("Yellow")
        circleFill.draw(win)
    else:
        circleFill = Circle (point, 10)
        circleFill.setFill("Red")
        circleFill.draw(win)
```

Comment: Why are you doing `if str(point) >= str(200)`? You're comparing strings?? Shouldn't you be comparing `int`s?

Comment: @Carl-Smith Ive tried that and it returns    'code' TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Point' 'code'

Comment: What is the comparison supposed to do? Normally, a point is two coordinates—an X value and a Y value. How is a point supposed to be a bigger or smaller number than 200? It's like asking whether Greenland is angrier than fog. Of course if you convert to strings, you can compare them—the "G" in Greenland is a higher letter than the "F" in "Fog"—but what does that tell you?

Comment: @abarnert Ive tried the if statement `If Point(point,point) >= Point(200,100):` and it returns with the error `if Point(point,point) >= Point(200,100):
TypeError: unorderable types: Point() >= Point()`

Comment: @Dwool: Well, what does it mean for one point to be bigger than another? Is `(10, 20)` bigger or smaller than `(25, 5)`? What are you actually trying to ask here? Imagine you drew a grid on your monitor: what part of your monitor should count as "true" here and what part should count as "false"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to compare a point to a number. This doesn't make any sense. Is the upper-right corner of your screen more than 200? What about the lower-right? Or the upper-left?

Of course you can convert them both to strings, then compare those, because you can always compare strings—but then you're just asking whether something like `'Point(1600, 0)'` would comes before or after `'200'` in the dictionary, which doesn't tell you anything useful.

Your next attempt, trying to compare a point to a point, still doesn't make any sense. Is `(1600, 20)` more or less than `(100, 1280)`? Of course there are various ways you could answer that (e.g., you could treat them as vectors rather than points and ask for their norms), but nothing that seems relevant to your question.

I think what you *might* want to do here is to compare the X coordinate of the point to a number:

```
if point.getX() >= 200:
```

That makes sense. That covers the whole right part of the screen, whether way up at the top or way down at the bottom, because whether you're at `(1600, 0)` or `(1600, 1200)`, that `1600` part is bigger than `200`.

That may not actually be what you want, but hopefully if it isn't, it gives you the idea to get unstuck.